# Powershell: Remove array elements lesser than a limit

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have a sorted numeric array in powershell.

I need a powershell command that'll remove all the elements from that array which are less than a particular value.

Eg: `if array is [270 271 272 274]`
`Value = 273`

Result array should be `[274]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$arr = 270,271,272,274
$value = 273

$arr = $arr -gt $value
$arr

274
```

Answer (score 1):

```
PS>@(10,20,30,40) | where {$_ -gt 30}
40
```